# Calculate expected value of piece-wise pdf

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have the following PDF of a random variable:

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
 1 & \text{if}\ \ \ 0<x<\frac{1}{2} \vee 1 < x < \frac{3}{2}\\ 
 0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$

How can i do to calculate the expected value?.

Comment: First ...How to write that PDF in Mathematica? Have you tried?

Comment: @belisarius Yes, like this: `Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x < 1/2 ||  1 < x < 3/2}, {0, false}}]`. The problem is that i dont know how to pass that to `ExpectedValue[]`

Comment: This is a function definition. Not PDF. Check how to define own PDF here http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html

Comment: @Nasser This is ok?: `ProbabilityDistribution[
 Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x < 1/2 ||  1 < x < 3/2}, {0, 
    false}}], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]`

Comment: hum.. Should not your function be `Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x < 1/2 || 1 < x < 3/2}, {0, True}}]` ? Otherwise, looks ok. Try it, like this `D0 = ProbabilityDistribution[Piecewise[{ {1, 0 < x < 1/2 || 1 < x < 3/2}, {0, True}}], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];` then you can plot it. `DiscretePlot[Evaluate[CDF[D0, x], {x, -10, 10}]]`, etc... see help for more information.

Comment: @Nasser It is supposed to be the pdf of a continous random variable, why the discrete plot?. The thing is how to pass that to ExpectedValue[]?

Comment: Just use Plot. I just typed DiscretePlot cause I was looking at example. Once you have Distribution, you can use `Mean` on it. As in `Mean[D0]` gives `3/4` There is also expectation, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expectation.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `ProbabilityDistribution`.

```
d = ProbabilityDistribution[
      Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x < 1/2}, {1, 1 < x < 3/2}}, 0], 
        {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

Mean[d]

(* 3/4 *)
```

Or alternatively `MixtureDistribution`.

```
d2 = MixtureDistribution[{1, 1}, {UniformDistribution[{0, 1/2}], 
   UniformDistribution[{1, 3/2}]}]

Mean[d2]

(* 3/4 *)
```

Since these are distributions all sorts of functions work with them.  For example, you can easily compute other expected values using `Expectation`.

```
Expectation[Log[x], Distributed[x, d]]

(* 1/2 (-2 - Log[2] + Log[27/8]) *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use $E(X)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}x \, PDF(x)\, dx$

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x < 1/2 || 1 < x < 3/2}, {0, false}}]
ExpectedValue=Integrate[x f[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

yields 3/4.